# How to capture the content of the response object returned by a rest api return in jersey in case the rest api throws 500 internal server error

Tags: java, rest, api

I am trying to call a post rest api from a java class which returns a pojo java object as a response.

The problem is I need to capture that response object in all the scenarios even when the api throws exception with http status 500 Internal server error.

If I hit the api with postman in case of 500 internal server error I could see the response in the postman with appropriate error messages as api returns http status 500 in case of validation errors.

But while calling the same api from java I am unable to capture the response as it goes to catch block and the response object returns null in that case so I am unable to capture the validation messages.

I am calling the rest api from my java client class using javax.ws.rs.client libraries where I capture the response in a pojo class shared by api specs.

In case the api is successful I am able to catch the response in my pojo class but in case off 500 internal server error I am unable to catch the response.

```
// this is the pojo class mapped to response content returned by the api 
UwbIntegrationCreateResponse response = null;
try {
  ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
  clientBuilder.property("com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.client.ssl.config", 
 "defaultSSLConfig");
  Client client = clientBuilder.register(MediatorService.class).build();
  WebTarget target = client
      .target("apiUrl");
 //api url is the rest api uri
  Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = 
 target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
  GenericType<UwbIntegrationCreateResponse> type = new 
 GenericType<UwbIntegrationCreateResponse>() {
  };
  response = invocationBuilder
      .post(Entity.entity(xmlContent, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML),
            type);
  logger.debug("Plan id created from upp is....." + 
response.getCreated().getPlanId());
  logger.debug("Proxy id created from upp is....." + 
response.getCreated().getProxyId());

}
catch (Exception e) {
// code enters the catch block in case of any exception and my response 
  content is null although while calling the same api from postman retuens 
  the appropriate error messages wrapped in the response object
  logger.debug(response);
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I expect somehow to captue the content of response object even when the code enters the catch block.